# Where is the coding style of cppreference defined?

Tags: c++, coding-style, std

I saw many example codes on cppreference.
For instance, the following URL has one code.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

From the example above, We can observe that the indent for braces are different over `struct` and `function` as follows.

```cpp
struct Foo { // left-brace is on the same line with the name of the struct 
    std::vector<int> mem = {1, 2, 3}; // default indent seems 4 spaces
    std::vector<int> mem2;
    Foo() : mem2{-1, -2, -3} {}
}; // right-brace starts with a new line

std::pair<std::string, std::string> f(std::pair<std::string, std::string> p)
{ // left-brace starts with a new line for function
    return {p.second, p.first}; // list-initialization in return statement
} // right-brace starts with a new line for function

int main()
{ // same as above
 //...
} // same as above
```

Where is the coding style described?

Comment: It's called Stroustrup style

Answer (score 3):

The style on cppreference is described @ [Help:Manual of style](https://en.cppreference.com/w/Help:Manual_of_style) (`Code formatting`)

For *Spacing and indentation* a [K&R variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Variant:_1TBS_.28OTBS.29) is used.

> If the parameters of a function span several lines, the indentation of all parameters matches the opening parenthesis. The same goes for template parameters.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> #include <vector>
>
> std::vector<int, MyAllocator> v;
>
> int complex_function(int long_param_name,
>                      int& another_param_name);
>
> int main(int argc, char** argv)
> {
>     if (argc == 2) {
>         v.push_back(23);
>     }
> }
> ```

That said, cppreference is a wiki and other formats may slip through the cracks.

Comment: While MoS exists, nobody is actively enforcing it, and "cppreference coding style" is effectively the style of the most active editors

Answer (score 1):

There is no strict code style on cppreference. Even on the referenced page two different styles for functions used in **Notes** and **Example**. If you follow the links on that page you will also find different code styles used for structs.

On the referenced page:

```
int main() {
  X x;
  X x2 = X { x }; // copy-constructor (not aggregate initialization)
  Q q;
  Q q2 = Q { q }; // initializer-list constructor (not copy constructor)
}

int main()
{
    int n0{};     // value-initialization (to zero)
    int n1{1};
```

On the second link on that page:

```
struct A
{
    A() { }         // converting constructor (since C++11)  
    A(int) { }      // converting constructor
    A(int, int) { } // converting constructor (since C++11)
};
```